# need help to use an api response in my code

Tags: node.js, twitch

To start off I am a noob at this coding game. started a couple of days ago. i am making a chatbot for twitch to use in my channel for fun. got the bot up and going and started to make commands. I am hoping to create an uptime command and have managed to get as far as requesting the data from the helix API but I am now completely stumped on how to "use" it.

```
const querystring = require("querystring"),
    fetch = require("node-fetch");

const CLIENT_ID = "###";
const STREAMS_URL = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams/";

var started_at = ""
const qs = querystring.stringify({
    user_login: "lil__gizmo"

});
const qUrl = `${STREAMS_URL}?${qs}`;
const fetchArgs = {
    headers: {
        "Client-ID": CLIENT_ID,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "###"
    }
};
fetch(qUrl, fetchArgs)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

the response I get is

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: '38236753072',
      user_id: '63931875',
      user_name: 'Lil__Gizmo',
      game_id: '497057',
      type: 'live',
      title: 'FEAR THE REAPERS!!!',
      viewer_count: 6,
      started_at: '2020-05-23T13:09:18Z',
      language: 'en',
      thumbnail_url: 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_lil__gizmo-{width}x{height}.jpg',
      tag_ids: [Array]
    }
  ],
  pagination: {}
}
```

I am trying to take the `started_at` property of the returned object and use it in my code.

Comment: console.log(data.data[0].started_at)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `async-await` syntax

You making async operation so you have to do this operation in function.

```
let data;

async function getData() {
    try {
        data = await fetch(qUrl, fetchArgs).then(res => res.json());
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

getData();

//Wait for 2 minutes to get data from server
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(data.data[0].started_at);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: i tried to implement this code, i admit i don't understand it fully, but when i ran it there was nothing logged to the console. if im correct the function getData is fetching the api request and waiting until it gets a response and then should log the response to console.

Comment: scratch that. little embarrassing but it took me a wee while to realise i needed to call the function to get a result. my bad, im a little new to all this :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
fetch(qUrl, fetchArgs)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can do:

```
fetch(qUrl, fetchArgs)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const { started_at } = data.data[0];
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can then do what you like with that variable.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i amended the code slightly

```
fetch(qUrl, fetchArgs)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const { game_id } = data.data[0];
        console.log(game_id)
    })
    // .then(data => console.log(data.data[0].started_at))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```
but i am unable to use the variable started_at outside the function. been trying to figure it out but stuck, any further help would be great. i am hoping to call started_at in another function

Comment: Nathan, This will not work. You can't access the variable outside of the function.

Comment: @PrathameshMore, the question never mentions using the variable outside of the promise. The question simply asks how to use started_at.

Comment: I fixed the question check it out.